# Checkbox is not copying exact values to other fields

Tags: javascript, performance

I have 5 6 fields that whom data I need to get in below 6 fields as well. The problem here is some of the values are not copying in the appropriate text fields.
I am posting my html as well. It's small form.

My html with js in it as well.

```
<input class="width_367" type="text" name="fname" id="email" required>

<input class="width_367" type="text" name="mname" id="pass" required>

<input class="width_367" type="text" name="lname" id="email" required>

<input class="width_367" type="text" name="address" id="address" required>

<input class="width_367" type="text" name="city" id="city"  required>
```

The checkbox:

```
<p align="left" style="width: 425px !important;">

<input type="checkbox" name="chkOption" value="yes">

&nbsp;Check here if Recipient Address is the same as Billing Address </p>

<input class="width_367" type="text" name="rfname" id="email" />

<input class="width_367" type="text" name="rmname" id="pass" />

<input class="width_367" type="text" name="rlname" id="email" />

<input class="width_367" type="text" name="raddress" id="address" />

<input class="width_367" type="text" name="rcity" id="city" />

onclick="javascript: if (chkOption.checked){

  rfname.value=fname.value;
  rmname.value=mname.value;
  rlname.value=lname.value;                                         
    raddress.value=address.value;
    rcity.value=city.value;
    rstate.value=state.value;                       
    recstate.value=usestate.value;
    rCountry.value=Country.value;
    rzip.value=zip.value;
    remail.value=email.value;
}else{
    rfname.value = '';
    rmname.value = '';
    rlname.value = '';
    raddress.value = '';
    rcity.value = '';
    rstate.value = '';
    recstate.value = '';
    rCountry.value = '';
    rzip.value = '';
    remail.value = '';
  }"
```

Comment: IDs in HTML must be unique

Comment: you mean all should be unique? means each fields should be unique?

Comment: Your IDs are not unique. They must be for valid HTML

Comment: Yes, All IDs must be unique

Comment: problem is address, city and zip value is saying UNDEFINED. please see my js code as well that is run on onclick of checkbox. please help

Comment: @splig can you please post valid HTML ids for them? please do this for me...

Comment: @Satpal Sir only two values are coming else all say UNDEFINED. i dont know why these both are coming in below fields...

Comment: @Satpal yeah it is fixed but lname values is still says undefined. why?? ids are unique please

Comment: @Satpal thanks you both of you great help..... only problem now left is for lname..

Comment: thank you guys the problem is now solved.......;) @Satpal you are life saver buddy.. this is your second help for me......:)

Comment: Glad you got it solved :-)